# Using has in Helm Go Template

Tags: kubernetes-helm, go-templates, sprig-template-functions

## values.yaml

```
{{if (has 1 .Values.xs)}}
a: 42
{{ else }}
b: 1
c: 2
{{ end }}
```

## template.yaml

```
xs:
  - 1
  - 2
  - 3
```

I get an output of

```
b: 1
c: 2
```

How can I fix [it](https://helm-playground.com/#t=LQhQG9wSwMwAgBYEMDOcCMcB0A1JAbAVwFMUsAPNAXytCQC44AWAJgnDmPxWLhtABGjdKADGjNpE4A7ACZ9acIA&v=LQhQA8GcC5QAjsOBGei4CY1IMxA) so that I get an output of `a: 42` since `1` is in `[1,2,3]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the types not matching.

`{{ kindOf (first .Values.xs) }}` returns `float64`, while `{{ kindOf (1) }}` returns `int`.

An alternative is use `float64`, by either writing `1.0`, or you can cast it:

```
{{ if has (float64 1) .Values.xs }}
```

If converting to a `float64` isn't your idea of good, you can instead use strings on both the definition of the list and in your comparison.